# a small technical detail

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I would like to understand what it technically means that

```
regular monomorphisms are stable under pushouts.
```

And even yet more trivially what does it mean that $h:A\to B$ is stable under pushouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not meaningful for a single morphism to be stable under pushouts. A class $\mathcal M$ of morphisms, such as the regular monomorphisms, is said to be stable under pushouts if given a span $z\leftarrow x\to y$ with pushout $z\to p\leftarrow y$, if the map $z\leftarrow x$ is in $\mathcal M$ then so is the map $p\leftarrow y$.

Comment: Are there some variants or always if the map $z\leftarrow x$ is in $\mathcal M$ then so is the map $p\leftarrow y$ ?

Comment: Well, this is equivalent to saying that if $x\to y$ is in $\mathcal M$ then so is $z\to p$, by symmetry. You can also ask that pushouts reflect $\mathcal M$, which is something that happens for instance in sets when the square is also a pullback, so that if $z\to p$ is in $\mathcal M$ then so is $x\to y$, but that's much less common.